# How to work with scipy and extremely large numbers

Tags: python, scipy, scientific-computing

I would like to use scipy's special functions to work with extremely large numbers

```
alpha = 9999
def y(t):
    return 1 / (special.lambertw(alpha * math.exp(alpha-t)) + 1)
```

`math.exp` throws overflow error, which is not surprising. So I tried to use decimal module instead

```
alpha = 9999
def y(t):
    exp = decimal.Decimal(math.exp(1))
    exp = exp ** alpha
    exp = exp * decimal.Decimal(math.exp(-t))
    return 1 / (special.lambertw(alpha * math.exp(alpha-t)) + 1)
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc '_lambertw' not supported for the input types, and the 
inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to 
the casting rule ''safe''
```

`special.lambertw` comes from scipy

What would be the right way of handling this?

Comment: Afaik [`uint64`/`int64` and `float64`/`complex128` are the largest numbers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html), `numpy` can work with. One of the aspects, numpy is not consistent with Python 3 declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/index.html).  It includes an implementation of [`lambertw`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/powers.html#lambertw).

For example,

```
In [20]: import mpmath

In [21]: mpmath.mp.dps = 30

In [22]: alpha = 9999

In [23]: def y(t):
    ...:     return 1 / (mpmath.lambertw(alpha * mpmath.exp(alpha-t)) + 1)
    ...: 

In [24]: y(1.5)
Out[24]: mpf('0.000100015000749774938119797735952206')
```

In general, you won't be able to use scipy's special functions with extremely large values.  Much of the scipy code is implemented in C, C++ or Fortran and is limited to 64 bit floating point values, with a maximum value of about 1.8e308:

```
In [11]: np.finfo(np.float64).max
Out[11]: 1.7976931348623157e+308
```